# Is there a way to add a new columns in a pandas DataFrame based on equivalence of values beetwen two DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, one called df, and another called df_pag. df has the following columns:

| Projetos | Ano/Volume | Unidades |
| --- | --- | --- |

On the other hand, df_pag has the following colums:

| Projetos | Ano | Unidades | Paginação |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

These DataFrames originates from different Data Mining processes. I want to add a new column to df called 'Paginação', where its row value is pulled from df_pag if, and only if, df['Projetos'] = df_pag['Projetos'], df['Ano/Volume'] = df_pag['Ano'] and df['Unidades'] = df_pag['Unidades'].

Here is what I did:

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    for j in range(len(df_pag.index)):
        if df['Projeto'][i] == df_pag['Projeto'][j] and df['Ano/Volume'][i] == df_pag['Ano'][j] and df['Unidade'][i] == df_pag['Unidade'][j]:
            df['Paginação'][i] = df_pag['Páginação'][j]
```

**PS**. This is my first question on StackOverflow, therefore, if there is anything unclear please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It does make my code simpler and quicker. But it still returning a df without rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi what about this approach:

```py
result_df = ((df['Projetos'] == df_pag ['Projetos']) == (df['Ano/Volume'] == df_pag ['Ano'])) == (df['Unidades'] == df_pag ['Unidades'])
df['Paginação'] = df_pag ['Paginação'][result_df]
```

This places `NaN` values for locations in *Paginação* column where the condition in not satisfied.

If you want any other value in place of `NaN` use `.fillna()` like:

```py
result_df = ((df['Projetos'] == df_pag ['Projetos']) == (df['Ano/Volume'] == df_pag ['Ano'])) == (df['Unidades'] == df_pag ['Unidades'])
df['Paginação'] = df_pag ['Paginação'][result_df]
df['Paginação'] = df['Paginação'].fillna('my_value')
```